# How to use sprintf in Twig to format a number?

Tags: symfony, twig

I need to format a number. In PHP, I would use `sprintf("%05d",$lineNumber)`.

In a Symfony 2 Twig template, what code should I use?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Twig provides lots of [filters](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/index.html), take a look at [`format`](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/format.html) and [`number_format`](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/number_format.html).

Comment: @ChocoDeveloper Can you provide an example of how you done it?

Comment: @crmpicco check the link :) here it is anyway: `{{ "I like %s and %s."|format(foo, "bar") }}` and with translations as we might as well improve it :) `{{ "I like %s and %s."|trans|format(foo, "bar") }}`

Comment: @MediaVince Check my answer below. That worked perfect for me.

Comment: the twig docs for v2 now live here https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/index.html

Answer (score 18):

If `i` was 4 before, then after adding this to your Twig template:

`"%02d"|format(i)`

...it will become 04.

Comment: This is exact answer.